# Connecting Fingerprint Scanner without USB converter

Tags: uart

I'm trying to connect a fingerprint scanner without using a USB converter. I have it connected to pins 8 and 10 (GPIO14 and 15). I was following a tutorial but it required me to use the command
`ls /dev/ttyusb`. I know from other questions and answers on this forum that it's possible. People have suggested to use `ls /dev/serial0` but that doesn't work for me as I get the error "No such file or directory found." I've gotten the same errors with AMA0 and S0 for good measure.

I'm using a pi4 and have been fiddling with this for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to the tutorial: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/how-to-use-raspberry-pi-fingerprint-sensor-authentication/

Comment: so, you don't have `/dev/ttyS0` or `/dev/ttyAMA0`? By the way, I hope your fingerprint reader is 3.3V and not 5V as per the warning in that so-called *tutorial* warns - also, have you connected power and ground as well (not that this matters, since apparently you have NO serial devices in `/dev` for some reason

Comment: @Bravo Yes, both of those returned the same error as /dev/ttyusb.

Also, according to the tutorial (I know it's pretty bad, but they're hard to find), "If your sensor needs a higher voltage than 3.3V (and the maximum value is equal to or greater than 5V), you can connect the red cable to the 5V pin." 

Wouldn't that mean that if it's 5 V I should be fine putting it in the 5v power?

Comment: the issue is the voltage on the tx/rx pins ... if it's over 3.3V, you'll fry your pi GPIO pins

Comment: anyway, try adding `enable_uart=1` to your `/boot/config.txt` file ... it's odd, 2 of my pi's (3B and 3A+) need that, and 3 don't (4B 4B and 3A+) .... I would've put it down to the model, but the two 3A+ pi's behave differently!!! However, in my case, I DID have `/dev/serial1` (which is linked to `/dev/ttyAMA0`) so, the fact that you have NO `/dev/serial?` at all is odd

Comment: Oh,  which release of raspberry pi OS? And disregard the last part of the previous comment, I know why the two 3A+ behave differently :p

Comment: @Bravo Thank you so much! I'm not sure which release of the OS but I bought the pi less than a week ago and I'm pretty sure it's fully updated (Again, part of the tutorial.) Adding enable_uart=1 lets me see /dev/ttyAMA0 so thank you!

Comment: `I'm pretty sure it's fully updated` - that doesn't mean you have the latest Raspberry PI OS ... as that won't upgrade between major releases of (i.e buster -> bullseye) unless you make very specific changes. Having said that, if you used Raspberry Pi Imager, chances are you do have the latest (Bullseye). Having said all that, ttyAMA0 should be the serial port connected to bluetooth - you should be seeing `/dev/ttyS0`

Answer (score 0):

Just like @bravo suggested in the comments of my question, I needed to add `enable_uart=1` to my `/boot/config.txt` file. Then I was able to see `/dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: I think what you should do is run raspi-config, go to interface options, serial port, then say No for login shell over serial, and yes for serial enabled